# PHP MySQL Post Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

So I've been wrestling with this issue all day.  I can't seem to post anything into my table and I'm not sure why.

I've got a form built that has all the values that are being transferred for the _POST.  Any pointers would be great.

```
elseif ($request == 'POST') {

include 'header_post.php'; include 'topmain.php';

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$dlnum = $_POST['dlnum'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$height = $_POST['height'];
$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$hair = $_POST['hair'];
$eyes = $_POST['eyes'];
$ethnicity = $_POST['ethnicity'];
}
$query3 = "insert into ".$db_prefix."customer_det (fname, lname, dlnum, dob, address, city, state, zip, phone, height, weight, hair, eyes, ethnicity) 
           values ('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$dlnum."', '".$dob."', '".$address."', '".$city."', '".$state."', 
           '".$zip."', '".$phone."', '".$height."', '".$weight."', '".$hair."', '".$eyes."', '".$ethnicity."')";
```

Comment: Have you established a connection to the database?

Comment: Becides the obvious sql injection, you're never executing the query anywhere.

Comment: Please let me know what site you're doing this for so I can practice up on my SQL injection skills.  This is the most dangerous query I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `mysql_query` :

```
$query3 = mysql_query("insert..");
```

you should also add this before `$fname = $_POST['fname'];` to prevent the query at page load :

```
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){

 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 ....
 $query3 = mysql_query("insert..");
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it mgraph.

Answer (score 2):

Using MySQL connection in PHP:

```
mysql_connect('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASS');
@mysql_select_db('DB_NAME');
$query='insert into ...';
mysql_query($query);
```

But your query is prone to SQL injections, and you are advised to use MySQLi extension.

```
    $mysql = new mysqli('DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME');
    $query = 'insert into customer_det (
        fname,
        lname,
        dlnum,
        .......
    ) values (?,?,?,....,?)';
    $statement = $mysql->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('sss...', //How many ever fields are there, those many sssss. For Integer use i. s is for string fields. Example ssssisssi....
        $fname,
        $lname,
        $dlnum,
        .....);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();
    $mysql->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not performing query

use `$result=mysql_query($query3);`

Comment: Any idea why it's performing the query as soon as the page loads and not when it's submitted?

Comment: use `if(isset($_POST['hair'])){mysql_query($QUERY)}`

Answer (score 0):

There must be a query called.
use mysql_query();

As mentioned above, any variable using user inputted text that is stored in a database should be contained within the mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: As i mysql_real_escape_string($variable) or mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value'])

Comment: Both would work, but since the variables are already being used in the query, go with the first one.